# Having trouble understanding how to create an array of linkedlists

Tags: java, arrays, class, generics, linked-list

Ok, so I have been reading every google result about creating an array of linkedlist, and most of the stack overflow threads, but I don't really understand what they are doing. Do I need to create a seperate class that extends linkedlist and then create an array of that class?

I have tried a million different ways of arranging this code, but this is what I have at the moment.

```
public static int[][] genPerms(int numElements, int totPerms) {
    int permArray[][] = new int[totPerms][numElements];
    LinkedList<Integer>[] elementsLeftList = new LinkedList<Integer>[numElements];
```

The error is generic array creation. Can someone explain to me what is actually going on here.

In addition to the solutions below I was told you can create an array of head pointers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't currently create an array of generics in Java without going through a complicated process. Can you do the following instead?

```
List<LinkedList<Integer>> elementsLeftList = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
```

If you really need it as an array you can then get it from elementsLeftList.toArray() and cast the result.

You can read the following link for the explanation: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ104

Comment: This seems to work. When I am accessing elements of the underlying linked list, I access them like this right

            permArray[counter][elemsPlaced] = (int) elementsLeftList.get(counter).remove(eleWorkingWith); ?? thanks. I selected your answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

It's not allowed to create generic arrays, do the following

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    LinkedList<Integer>[] elementsLeftList = new LinkedList[numElements];
```

it works OK

Comment: or to avoid raw types: `LinkedList<Integer>[] elementsLeftList = new LinkedList<?>[numElements];`